# AWS: how to downgrade rds engine type from Aurora to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

The RDS is currently Aurora and I'm thinking of changing to Postgres and use a smaller instance type to save some cost. Downtime is accepted.

Can't seem to do this from the web console, guess I'll have to first create a snapshot, delete the db, and create a new db of postgres type, from the snapshot?

Apologies if the above steps sound weird and I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to do with snapshots. You will have to perform a `pg_dump` of the current database, and then load it into the RDS instance using `pg_restore`.